# Need help identifying diode symbol

Tags: mosfet, diodes, shift-register, symbol

I found this symbol which I've never seen before in pg. 12 of the [TI TPIC6B595 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b595.pdf) describing the output, it resembles a diode with an extra line at the cathode:
[image]

I recognize the zener diodes for the clamping circuitry but these ones do not have a value, they don't seem to be any type of thyristor symbol [from this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor#Types) either. At first I thought it could be the body diode of the FET but then the leftmost one wouldn't be there.

Comment: Huh. Now I'm curious too!

Comment: i suppose that these are parasitic diodes formed by the internal FET structure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is just a glitch of the desktop publishing software the TI use in pdf creation: compare an identical schematic, only with the regular body diode and diode symbols, in [TPIC6B273 POWER LOGIC OCTAL D-TYPE LATCH](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b273.pdf?ts=1632199070291), page 3/17.

[image: TPIC6B273]

Comment: That would make sense, here I thought it was shorthand for something else or there was some new type of diode :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, you just took the paranoia I already have when reading schematics to a whole new level... is this thing here a glitch?? ;) (Nice answer, +1)