# Which (Zener-like) component does this diode-like symbol represent?

Tags: diodes, identification, schematics, datasheet, symbol

I recently stumbled upon a TI datasheet ([TPIC6B595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b595.pdf), a 595-like power shift register) where they use a diode-like symbol I've never seen.

Datasheet excerpt, figure 13 at p.12 (yellow emphasis mine):

[image]

Reading the datasheet descriptions and schematics, one can infer it represents something that acts like a Zener diode and is used for overvoltage protection. However it does not represent a Zener, because in the same schematics there are Zener diodes represented with one of the usual symbols.

Do you know which component that symbol it is meant to represent and provide some info about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help identifying diode symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/587587/need-help-identifying-diode-symbol)

Comment: @Unimportant Doh! It seems my question is an exact duplicate of that question!

Comment: @Unimportant Oh, well, I'm voting to close my own question. I'm not deleting it just because it would help someone to pinpoint the same problem.